# Partial matching of Regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have a String that is incrementally built. While the string being built, it is matched as a whole by a regular expression and when a match is found, a certain task is performed.

My requirement is: If in the middle of the string building process it is found that there is no way an exact match will be found, then the string should be reset and the build process should be re-initiated.

For example if a regular expression is `"mada12gaskar"` and when a char `"3"` is added to an existing string `"mada1"` the string should be cleared and the build process should start over again as `"mada13"` will never match with `"mada12gaskar"`. Is this possible through Java regex API?

Comment: Provide an example of the code you are trying to write to clarify the requirement.  Regex is regex, so the matching should be possible, but you'll need other logic to "clear your String".

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is quite a good question to me.

Comment: Im quite not an expert, but why don't you simply store the last matching string (e.g. `mada1`) in an seperate variable which is overwritten with the next matching string? In case the given String (`mada13`) doesn't match, overwrite it with the last matching string, stored seperately..

Comment: You should add a concrete short example of what you want, because it seems nobody (except Marko Topolnik) understands the question as I understand it. As I understand it, if the regexp is `ab`, a doesn't match, so you continue and add another character: `ac`, and you would like to stop because there's no way adding characters to `ac` will ever match the regexp `ab`.

Comment: I'm quite interested in the subset of regexp you need to support. Which features do you need? Also, could you phrase your intent like _"I need to build all strings that match a particular regexp."_? Or is it more like _"I need to build a string that is matched by all of these thousand regexpes."_, or simply _"I need to know whether this string could be whole matched by this regexp if we appended something to it."_?

Comment: I mean " I need to know whether this string could be whole matched by this regexp if we appended something to it?". I am writing a generic framework where the regular expression is not known and will be configured at the time of implementation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I found a possible solution to your problem.

Look at [`Matcher#hitEnd()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#hitEnd%28%29) method:

> Returns true if the end of input was hit by the search engine in the
>   last match operation performed by this matcher.
>
> When this method returns true, then it is possible that more input
>   would have changed the result of the last search.

Now, simply match the regexp against your not-yet-fully-constructed String using a `Matcher` (obtainable via a `Pattern` instance) and look at the results:

- if it matched, you have your winner
- if it didn't match, look at `hitEnd()`:

  - if it's `true`, build more String and try again
  - if it's `false`, the current String could never be matched, you can drop it and start over

Comment: Hats off, my answer deleted.

Comment: Just one caveat: "if it's `false`, the current String could never be matched, you can drop it and start over"---actually you should *backtrack* and maybe find a different string with the same prefix.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I was equally surprised when I discovered the method. Still, there are some goodies to learn in the `Matcher` class, I don't know what half of the other methods do. About the backtracking - yeah, sure.

Comment: Many Thanks!. This seems to be my solution. I will try it.