# Approximate matching of regular expressions in java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, string-matching, approximation

i am looking something similar to
 `commons-text -LevenshteinDetailedDistance` but  **for regular expressions.**

```
e.g 
    LevenshteinDetailedDistance d = new LevenshteinDetailedDistance();
     LevenshteinResults levenshteinResults = d.apply("SomeText", "Some Text");
the result will be like below 
Distance: 1, Insert: 1, Delete: 0, Substitute: 0
```

//means - string are different by 1 character

Is there any similar library for approximate matching of regular expressions  in java  ?

e.g .

```
String regularEX = ".*Some Text 1.*"

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regularEX, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.MULTILINE);

pattern.matcher("anyPrefixText Some Text").matches(); // this will retrun false  - but as only one chatterer is missing - i want to get that difference
```

Is there any inbuilt library that i can use for this ?

i have already seen below questions but they are not helping
[Approximate regular expression library for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273115/approximate-regular-expression-library-for-java)
[Partial Matching of Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42073491/partial-matching-of-regular-expressions)
[Partial matching of Regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17773465/partial-matching-of-regular-expression)

Answer (score -1):

I don't thing there is such a library.  I'm not aware of anything that tells you how far you missed a match by.

Comment: There is a C library that does this ([TRE](https://laurikari.net/tre/about/)), but it has not yet been ported to Java.